# Create a file with the content of 2 other files, then sort the new file

Tags: sorting, pipe, cat, tee

I am using the following command: **cat < file1.txt | tee >> unsorted.txt | cat < file2.txt >> unsorted.txt | sort -r unsorted.txt > sorted.txt**

If i run this line once i get an error that the file unsorted.txt doesn't exist if i run it again then i get the second file sorted.txt with the correct data. I might be doing something wrong with the logic, but since the file unsorted is getting created why it fails to sort the file the first time, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just `cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort - r > sorted.txt`?

Comment: i need the content of file1 and file2 in a new file named unsorted then i need to sort the unsorted file to a new file name unsorted in the end i will have 2 new files. I need to keep the first file too, so my goal is to have 2 files in the end of the command.

Comment: So `cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | sort - r > sorted.txt`

Comment: I did use the "cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort - r > sorted.txt" and i added tee >> unsorted Result: cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | sort  -r  > sorted.txt. Thank you for your tip, thankfully i didnt see your second reply so i understood more by testing.

Comment: Your question is not specifically related to Kali Linux, and based on your question you seem to be a beginner. In this case you should use a distribution for general use instead of Kali. see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/330217

Answer (score 0):

You had the command:

```
cat < file1.txt | tee >> unsorted.txt | cat < file2.txt >> unsorted.txt |
sort -r unsorted.txt > sorted.txt
```

There are numerous problems with this.  Dissecting it step by step:

1. `cat < file1.txt |` — works OK but the redirection is not needed; `cat file1.txt` would work too.
2. `tee >> unsorted.txt |` — the `tee` command reads its standard input and writes one copy to each named file in its argument list and another to its standard output.  The `>> unsorted.txt` redirection means that the standard output goes to the file and not to the pipe.  No arguments are provided to `tee`, so it only writes to standard output.
3. `cat < file2.txt >> unsorted.txt` — the `cat` command reads either the files named in its argument list or reads its standard input.  Since no files are named (a program doesn't see the file names associated with redirection symbols), it reads its standard input.  That comes from `file2.txt` and writes to `unsorted.txt` — it ignores standard input, which doesn't matter, I suppose, since the pipe never sends any data (see point 2).  You have two processes appending to `unsorted.txt`; the results are not guaranteed, but you might be OK.
4. `sort -r unsorted.txt > sorted.txt` — fortunately, `sort` reads from command line arguments, defaulting to standard input only if there are no files.  However, `sort` runs while the `tee` and `cat` are writing to `unsorted.txt` — the behaviour is not controlled.

To summarize: you are using I/O redirections too liberally and are confusing yourself by doing so.

It would be far simpler to use:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | sort -r -o sorted.txt
```

You could use `> sorted.txt` instead of `-o sorted.txt`, but one advantage of the `-o file` option is that the output file can also be one of the input files and the input file will not be destroyed until after it is read.  That isn't critical here (there are no input file names), but it can be important and useful.

This command writes the contents of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in sequence to the standard input of `tee`, which writes a copy of that information to `unsorted.txt` and also a copy to its standard output, which is also the standard input of `sort`.  The `sort` command has the `-r` flag (for reverse sorting) that you used, and the output file is specified; there are no input file arguments, so it sorts standard input.  There is no indeterminacy in this pipeline.  There are also no `<` or `>` or `>>` redirections (one is optional, though).